# AWS Auto Scaling Group with defined duration spot instances and multiple instance types

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, autoscaling, amazon-ec2-spot-market, spot-instances

I would like to specify the following auto scaling group:

- min instances: 1
- max instances: M
- instance type: m5.xlarge, c5.xlarge, r5.xlarge
- spot instance: yes
- defined duration: 3 hours

Using a Launch Template, I can specify defined duration spot instances, but only a single instance type.

Using the Auto Scaling Group configuration, I can specify spot instances with multiple instance types, but not defined durations.

Is there a way to get all three? Multiple instance types, spot instances, and defined durations/spot blocks.

Comment: Why do you need the defined duration when the instances are in an AutoScaling Group?  Can you have a scaling policy terminate instances when the groups usage is low?  Or when the instances are done running a job have them call terminate-instance-in-auto-scaling-group on themselves?

Answer (score 0):

According to [New – EC2 Auto Scaling Groups With Multiple Instance Types & Purchase Options | AWS News Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-auto-scaling-groups-with-multiple-instance-types-purchase-options/), you can specify multiple instance types in an Auto Scaling group by specifying **Combine purchase models and instances**. This also lets you combine Spot and On-Demand

However, because Auto Scaling groups will launch/terminate instances based upon activity, it is not possible to launch a [Defined Duration spot instance](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-ec2-spot-blocks-for-defined-duration-workloads/) as part of an Auto Scaling group. However, you could launch it separately and then use [AttachInstances](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_AttachInstances.html) to add it to the Auto Scaling group. You could then set [Instance Protection](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/ec2/APIReference/API_SetInstanceProtection.html) on that instance to prevent it from being terminated.

Comment: Small clarification: Instance protection only keeps it from being picked for termination when the desired goes down.  It does NOT help prevent spot terminations or healthcheck replacements